# Import Material icons into Cordova Android Studio

Tags: html, css, cordova, android-studio, google-material-icons

I am using cordova 6.0 in android studio. i want to use google material-design icons in html page for my personal project, but when i use the CDN of google icons it doesn't get rendered.

Comment: A little more detail might be helpful... see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

If you need **only Icons** then [material-design-icons](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/). The setup information guide is given there.

If you need whole material framework (Paper Elements, Cards and Floating Action Button) including fonts then [getmdl.io](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html)